# bat cmd how modify %%i

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to bypass folders recursively, and if it meets the TGA file, then execute convert (imagemagic).

```
echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for / r "D: \ L2" %% i in ("* .tga") do (
    
     set name_old = %% i

     rem set name_new =! name_old!
     set name_new =% name_new:~0,-3%png

     convert% name_old% %name_new%

     echo del% name_old%
)

endlocal
exit / b 0
```

Unfortunately, I do not understand how to get name_new right way.

Comment: Just curious: where have you got this totally broken syntax?

Comment: @wOxxOm  , never seen anyone ever try to do that.  Boggles my old brain.

Answer (score 1):

Don't insert spaces arbitrarily, it breaks the syntax.

Also you don't need delayed expansion to change the file extension, simply use `%%~dpn` prefix (see more examples by running `for /?`)

The correct syntax is:

```c
for /r "D:\L2" %%i in ("*.tga") do (
     convert "%%i" "%%~dpni.png"
     del "%%i"
)
exit /b 0
```

P.S. The last line isn't needed for a standalone .BAT file, it's useful only to return from a [subroutine](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html).